PDF form not fillable when sent to recipient
I'm using the DocuSign SDK for VS.Net. I can successfully acquire an access token, send a file to a recipient, sign the file, and return it. The PDF form, however, is not editable. I confirmed that the PDF is fillable before it goes into the Envelope. I'm sure I'm missing something small. Any help would be appreciated.
I'm using the developers URI if that matters.
I tried adding the PDF form into a DocuSign envelope and sending it to a recipient. I was expecting the PDF form to be fillable but it was not.

To transform PDF form fields into DocuSign tabs, you need to set the transformPdfFields property on the documents whose fields you want to transform.
https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/tabs/pdf-transform/
    EnvelopeDefinition envelopeDefinition = new EnvelopeDefinition();
    envelopeDefinition.EmailSubject = "Please sign this document";
    Document doc1 = new Document();
    // MUST SET THIS LINE 
    doc1.TransformPdfFields = "true";

    string doc1B64 = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

    doc1.DocumentBase64 = doc1B64;
    doc1.Name = "Lorem Ipsum"; // can be different from actual file name
    doc1.FileExtension = "pdf";
    doc1.DocumentId = "3";


Out of curiosity, do you use VB.NET, not C# to code?

We're a VB house. Also, I prefer VB.

This is cool, I don't know too many people who use VB.NET for Docusign APIs. Would you mind contacting me at inbar.gazit@docusign.com ? Maybe we can discuss other things...

Sure, what did you have in mind?

Maybe featuring you in our monthly "Developer Spotlight" series?

That sounds great!

Can you send me an email then? or tell me what your email is?

Rlhxeno@gmail.com
